Delete Row based on Cell Value
I have code that is not working, but it is close.  This code is supposed to delete rows based on a value in column B.  If the row does not have that value, delete it.  Nothing happens when I run it, though if I change the "does not equal" function to "equals", it deletes the rows that have the referenced values.  Why wont this code do the opposite when I put <> in place of =?
Dim arcArray As Variant
Dim d As Integer
arcArray = Array("Tanker Offer Data", "Truck Offer Data", "Pipeline Offer Data", "Barge & SDraft Offer Data", "Offeror Max Monthly")

    Dim ws5 As Worksheet
    For Each arcSheet In arcArray
    
            sheets(arcSheet).Select
            lastrow = sheets(arcSheet).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            Range("B6:B" & lastrow).Select
            For d = 6 To lastrow
            
        If ActiveCell.Value <> ActiveSheet.Range("E1").Value Then
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
            Next d
            
    Next arcSheet


The problem is the use of ActiveCell. Also, if you're deleting in a loop, you need to loop backwards. It's better not to delete in a loop. Also, d should be declared As Long, not As Integer.

Yes lots wrong here. Use worksheet variables and range variables so you can clearly specify which sheet and ranges you are working with. No need to use ".select" ever!


It's worth to read:

How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA

Deleting cells or rows causes cells to shift, which can lead to unexpected outcomes. It is crucial to use the correct approach and exercise caution.

Collect all desired range and delete it all at once


Option Explicit
Sub demo()
    Dim arcArray As Variant, vCell, delRng As Range
    Dim d As Long, oSht As Worksheet, c As Range
    arcArray = Array("Tanker Offer Data", "Truck Offer Data", "Pipeline Offer Data", "Barge & SDraft Offer Data", "Offeror Max Monthly")
    For Each arcSheet In arcArray
        Set oSht = Sheets(arcSheet)
        vCell = oSht.Range("E1").Value
        lastrow = oSht.Range("B" & oSht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set delRng = Nothing
        For d = 6 To lastrow
            Set c = oSht.Cells(d, "B")
            If c.Value <> vCell Then
                If delRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set delRng = c
                Else
                    Set delRng = Application.Union(delRng, c)
                End If
            End If
        Next d
        If Not delRng Is Nothing Then
            delRng.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next arcSheet
End Sub

